# How do I remove this tooltip in header?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

[image: example]

This special header tooltip appears when I click on the row header. The sum is not a useful aggregation here. How can I edit it or turn it off? Regular tooltips for this worksheet are turned off.

My last resort will be to hover a blank box over the header region so it cannot be clicked by a user, but I'd rather them be able to click to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is by turning off the tooltip features as follows:

[image]

This will remove the tooltips completely

Comment: Thanks Debayan. Unfortunately, the tooltips are already set to off. This is a different type of information box that may or may not be called a "tooltip" in Tableau. It appears on a click rather than a hover and appears over a header rather than a data component.